# vscode-icons extension: Icon image is not changed

Tags: icons, vscode-extensions

[use extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)

We use Mac

```json
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"vsicons.customIconFolderPath": "/Users/<your_user>/Library/Application Support/Code/User/vsicons-custom-icons",
"vsicons.associations.folders": [
 {
   "icon": "templates",
   "extensions": ["application"],
   "format": "svg"
 },
 {
   "icon": "molecules",
   "extensions":["domain"],
   "format": "svg"
 },
 {
   "icon": "organisms",
   "extensions": ["infrastructure"],
   "format": "svg"
 },
 {
   "icon": "pages",
   "extensions": ["presentation"],
   "format": "svg"
 }
],
```

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the name of the "icon" to something appropriate, but it remained transparent, so it is likely that the image itself is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like me.
In the "extensions" field you should specify the desired folder name
[vsicons-screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YG2U.png)

After, In the "vsicons-custom-icons" folder create two files:

1. first one uses the prefix "folder_type_" + "name" ( in my case it is "package") + format. So I got the file with the name "folder_type_package.svg"
2. second one uses the prefix "folder_type_" + "name" + suffix "_opened" + format. And I got the second file with the name "folder_type_package_opened.svg"

[vsicons-screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WzJv.png)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do as you answered but it did not work. Could you please let me know the URLs and images you referred to if possible?

Comment: Sorry for the long answer. Unfortunately, I have no this image URL. I made these screenshots from my PC and save them locally.

Comment: I see that you save your icons in the next folder "/Users/<your_user>/Library/Application Support/Code/User/vsicons-custom-icons". That is the default folder in Mac OS. Try to remove the "vsicons.customIconFolderPath" : .... from settings.json

Comment: In other cases show me please the icon files name and path

Comment: Thank you!!!" I removed "vsicons.customIconFolderPath" and now it works correctly!
Thank you for resolving this long unknown error.

Comment: By the way, the reason it worked when I removed it was because "/Users/<your_user>/Library/Application Support/Code/User/vsicons-custom-icons". is the default icon location, and if you want to put icons in other locations, you set "vsicons.customIconFolderPath", right?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.  But I'm not a specialist to insist on this =)